# How to generate strings for all subfolders

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I want to generated localizable strings for all .m files in my project.
However they're not all dumped in the Class folder, they're in several directories (many of them).

What's the best way to parse the entire tree and generate the strings to localized using genstrings command?

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744401/how-to-use-genstrings-across-multiple-directories

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the project directory:

```
find . -name "*.m" | xargs genstrings <any options go here>
```

presumably the easiest way. `xargs` will put the filenames at the end of the command.