# removing strings created with genstrings

Tags: xcode, localization, genstrings

I started to localize my application. I used `genstrings` to create the localizable.strings. This worked fine. Now I have worked on the app and have removed a couple of the strings and replaced them with icons. Is there a way to tell `genstrings` to remove all strings, that are no longer in use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't run genstrings again on all .m -files in your project. Generally there will be generated a new file that includes just the actual strings that could be found on the last run. If it doesn't work, just rename your old file and run following comment again:

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o directory/filename.lproj
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3511929/1141395