# Issue with genstrings for Swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, localization, xcode6

`genstrings` works well to extract localizable content from .m file as,

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj
```

But, not working for .swift file as,

```
find . -name \*.swift | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj
```

Answer (score 36):

The `genstrings` tool works fine with swift as far as I am concerned. Here is my test:

```
// MyClass.swift
let message = NSLocalizedString("This is the test message.", comment: "Test")
```

then, in the folder with the class

```
# generate strings for all swift files (even in nested directories)
$ find . -name \*.swift | xargs genstrings -o .

# See results
$ cat Localizable.strings
/* Test */
"This is the test message." = "This is the test message.";
$
```

Comment: I see, genstrings tracks NSLocalizedString, but I have used string extension like localizedString(). So my string becomes "This is the test message.".localizedString() and that's why it is not being tracked

Comment: Well, you know what to do. Your problem can be solved with one smart global text replace operation. Start by ticking the checkmark above ;-).

Comment: note: `genstrings` does not work for any long-form (arguably best practice) usage: `NSLocalizedString("checkout-okbtn", value: "Ok", comment: "in cart checkout, the button that pays")` [radar issue](https://openradar.appspot.com/22133811)

Comment: I also (just) found out that genstrings does _not_ work correctly with my Swift files in a mixed Objective-C/Swift project! I am most definitely using `NSLocalizedString` with string literals only. For example, this message is not found: `localizedName = NSLocalizedString("Popular Now", comment: "Name of the menu item to select content that is popular now")` -- This is a really big deal. I must find a solution for this a.s.a.p. I'll be looking into philipp's recommendation to try out https://github.com/KeepSafe/genstrings_swift

Comment: Wait, I just realize why. I'm running a genstrings command where I'm only looking for *.m files. Let me see if I can alter that to find both *.m and *.swift in one go...

Comment: Yes, working fine for both Objective-C and Swift in my mixed project now I changed the command to the following: `cd ~/Workspace/ios-ecentral-app/ECentral/;find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) | xargs genstrings -o ECentral/localization/en.lproj/'`

Answer (score 5):

I believe `genstrings` works as intended, however Apple's `xargs` approach to generate strings from all your project's files is flawed and **does not properly parse paths containing spaces**.

That might be the reason why it's not working for you.

Try using the following:

`find . -name \*.swift | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 genstrings -o .`

Comment: This solved my problem with some declarations that included newline. Thank you!

Comment: `find . -name \*.swift -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o .`, no need for replacing anything with `tr`.

Answer (score 4):

We wrote a command line tool that works for Swift files and merges the result of apples `genstrings` tool.
It allows for `key` and `value` in `NSLocalizedString`

https://github.com/KeepSafe/genstrings_swift

Comment: philipp, I have a project that is a mix of Objective-C and Swift. I have found that the `genstrings` tool only finds the message from the Objective-C source code. This genstrings_swift tool, can it be run on a mixed-code project like mine and find all the messages in one go, or do I need to follow a sequence of steps?

Comment: This is the genstrings command I am using now, by the way: `cd ~/Workspace/ios-ecentral-app/ECentral/;find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o ECentral/localization/en.lproj/`

Comment: Oh wait... doh! I should edit that command to include *.swift...!

Comment: Okay, fixed by changing my alias to the following:   `alias genstringsECentral='cd ~/Workspace/ios-ecentral-app/ECentral/;find ./ -type f \( -iname \*.m -o -iname \*.swift \) | xargs genstrings -o ECentral/localization/en.lproj/'` -- works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative tool called [SwiftGenStrings](https://github.com/kayak/SwiftGenStrings)

Hello.swift

```
NSLocalizedString("hello", value: "world", comment: "Hi!")
```

SwiftGenStrings:

```
$ SwiftGenStrings Hello.swift 

/* Hi! */
"hello" = "world";
```

Apple genstrings:

```
$ genstrings Hello.swift

Bad entry in file Hello.swift (line = 1): Argument is not a literal string.
```

Disclaimer: I worked on SwiftGenStrings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here:
[How to use genstrings across multiple directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744401/how-to-use-genstrings-across-multiple-directories)

```
find ./ -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having with `find/genstrings` was twofold:

1. When it reached folder names with spaces (generated by the output of `find`), it would exit with an error
2. When it reached the file where I had my custom routine defined, it was giving me an error when trying to parse my actual function definition

To fix both those problems I'm using the following:

```
find Some/Path/ \( -name "*.swift" ! -name "MyExcludedFile.swift" \) | sed "s/^/'/;s/$/'/" | xargs genstrings -o . -s MyCustomLocalizedStringRoutine
```

To summarize, we use the `find` command to both **find and exclude** your Swift files, then pipe the results into the `sed` command which will wrap each file path in quotes, then finally pipe that result into the `genstrings` command

Answer (score 0):

Xcode now includes a powerful tool for extracting localizations.

Just select your project on the left then Editor menu >> Export localizations.

You'll get a folder with **all the text** in your files as well as the `Localizable.strings` and `InfoPlist.strings`

More details here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html